# What is $346_7 + 165_7 $when expressed in base-$7$?

Tags: number-systems

Hi I used a converter to do this question - and answered the second option. But still unsure, if I made it right.

[image]

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can eliminate the other answers by simply considering the units. The units digits are $6$ and $5$. Their sum is $11$, which is congruent to $4$ mod $7$. So the solution must have a $4$ in the units digit.

Comment: And then we can conclude 544 must be the right answer ;)

Comment: Sure. You could also rule out $511$, their sum in decimal, and $277$ (for the leftmost digit being too small).

Answer (score 1):

$$346_7+165_7=(3\cdot7^2+4\cdot7^1+6\cdot7^0)+(1\cdot7^2+6\cdot7^1+5\cdot7^0)=$$
$$=277=5\cdot7^2+4\cdot7^1+4\cdot7^0=544_7$$